# Razor page jumps to top on Chart mouseover

Tags: javascript, c#, css, blazor, syncfusion

I have a Blazor Web app that displays weather data using `Syncfusion Blazor Charts`. This is how I reference it in my index.razor.

```
<div class="linechart">
    <h3>Mean Temperatures and Precipitation for @DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")</h3>
    <WeatherChart Temperatures="@Temperatures" Width="@Width" />
</div>
```

Everytime I hover over the chart the page "jumps" back to the top. That does not happen when hovering over the `<h3>` or indeed any other section of my page. So the culprit must be the behaviour of the chart itself.

Here is the code for the chart just for the sake of completeness but there is nothing in here that would explain what's going on:

```
<SfChart Width="@Width" >
<ChartPrimaryXAxis Title="Day" ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category" LabelIntersectAction="LabelIntersectAction.Hide">
    <ChartAxisMajorGridLines Width="0" Color="blue" />
</ChartPrimaryXAxis>
<ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Temperatures"></ChartPrimaryYAxis>
<ChartAxes>
    <ChartAxis Name="YAxis" OpposedPosition="true" Title="Precipitation in mm"/>
</ChartAxes>
    <ChartSeriesCollection>
        <ChartSeries DataSource="@Temperatures" XName="X" High="High" Low="Low" Type="ChartSeriesType.RangeArea" Width="2" Fill="red" Opacity="0.1">
            <ChartMarker Visible="true" Height="5" Width="5" Shape="ChartShape.Circle" IsFilled="true" />
        </ChartSeries>
        <ChartSeries DataSource="@Temperatures" XName="X" YName="Precipitation" Type="ChartSeriesType.Column" YAxisName="YAxis" Fill="#FEC007" ColumnWidth="1.5">
        </ChartSeries>        
    </ChartSeriesCollection>

    <ChartLegendSettings Visible="true" Position="LegendPosition.Top" />
</SfChart>
```

I do have a `JavaScript` browser resize event but that has nothing to with it either I don't think as the bug occurs regardless of screen size.

Comment: "_but that has nothing to with it either_" - not saying you're wrong, but I can't count the number of times I've said things like that, only to find out that it **was** the problem. I would suggest you cut down your code to the barest minimum that still repros the issue. Makes it much easier to confirm what is and isn't contributing to the problem

Comment: So I commented out everything related to the resize script and nothing has changed. That's not it then.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to produce an [absolute minimum sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that repros the problem and post it here. I would start by cutting out the chart and see if it's that. If it is, then contact the vendor for support. If not, post your minimum sample here (remember it needs to be complete for us to try it, so full code and no proprietary components) and we can take a look.